# Error 400: invalid_request Invalid parameter value for prompt: Invalid prompt: cons

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets-api

I am creating a plugin in WordPress where I am trying to make the Google sheet script work but I can't find a way.

I tried all the code available on here and different sources but I can't find anything to make it work. This is the error I get:

> Open the following link in your browser:
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=390081316396-0es6irrbq1ccj01uvhlqvrbc0eo9eopq.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.suma.pro%2Fapp%2F&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets.readonly&prompt=consent
> Enter verification code: Fatal error: Uncaught
> InvalidArgumentException: Invalid code in
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:176
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/suma-app.php(125):
> Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('') #1
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292):
> SumaApp->getClient('') #2
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-includes/plugin.php(484):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-settings.php(560): do_action('init') #5
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-config.php(90):
> require_once('/home/suma/publ...') #6
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-load.php(37):
> require_once('/home/suma/publ...') #7
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once('/home/suma/publ...') #8
> /home/suma/public_html/app/index.php(17):
> require('/home/suma/publ...') #9 {main} thrown in
> /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php
> on line 176

```
    function getClient()
    {
    define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Sumaapptest');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'inc/vendor/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setRedirectUri( 'https://www.suma.pro/app/');
    $client->setPrompt('consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
    }

    function suma_order_status_change_custom($this_get_id){

    // Get the API client and construct the service object.
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    $spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
    $range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
    $values = $response->getValues();

    if (empty($values)) {
    print "No data found.\n";
    } else {
    print "Name, Major:\n";
    foreach ($values as $row) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
    }
    }


    // echo $this_get_id;
    //   die();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)?

Comment: Yes I am using quickstart

Comment: In which case there must be something you are doing differently because the quickstart works for me. Did you create the GCP project, oauth credentials etc? Did the app ask for authorization?

Comment: Yes after asking for authorization I am redirected to above error.

Comment: Check the video, please.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F5YGSL9LBd5QBDFXAgtAMhDNkMjLVgg7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I solve the previous issue. Do you have any idea why I am getting the below issue now?

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: file does not exist in /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:839 Stack trace: #0 /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/process_google_sheets.php(12): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('/home/suma/publ...')

Answer (score 0):

#### Check your OAuth Client IDs

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/

Navigate to APIs & Services and take a look at this screen.

You should see that the **type** of client IDs is Web Application. The message that you are getting looks like you have made it a "Desktop" type.

Ensure that you have followed the steps in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) exactly and *then* make it work together with wordpress after the quickstart works without issue.

[image]

Comment: Check below image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V4Mmxhl-ahfkbWx5hZO6zHqHyZmWQ1HP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which one are you using?

Comment: Web application

Comment: are you using the service account?

Comment: Yes, I had created it. But I am not sure either I need that or not.

Comment: I think you must have the wrong project or your credentials.json file is wrong.

Comment: and that error is happening after google authentication did you check above video I share?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230800/discussion-between-iansedano-and-zaheer-abbas).

Comment: Verification Status
Verification not required
Your consent screen is being shown, but your app has not been reviewed so your users may not see all of your information, and you will not be able to request certain OAuth scopes. Learn more

Comment: If that is the case then you need to either set your app to INTERNAL / Testing, or get your app reviewed.

Comment: I solve the previous issue. Do you have any idea why I am getting the below issue now?

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: file does not exist in /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:839 Stack trace: #0 /home/suma/public_html/app/wp-content/plugins/suma-app/inc/process_google_sheets.php(12): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('/home/suma/publ...')

Comment: What was the previous issue? If my answer was part of the solution would you accept it (✓) or if it was not, please add your own answer and accept it?  If you have another new question then the best thing is to create a new question, not ask more in the comments. This makes the site more useful to future visitors, thank you.

Comment: The issue was I have to give permissions to particular users to access the app from OAuth consent screen section. Now everything is working. Thanks for your help.